# Detecting Actual Window Size in IE When Using CSS3 Zoom Property

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, css, doctype

I am facing a weird issue here. I know IE behaves rather differently from other browsers while calculating windows's height and width, but I am quite stunned with what I found out. Here's the code..

```
var i = 1; 
setInterval(function() {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        $("body").css("zoom","0.15");
    else
        $("body").css("zoom","1");
    i++;
    console.log(i+" ("+$(window).width()+" X "+$(window).height()+")");                
},1000 );
```

The code is pretty straightforward. What I am doing is every alternate second I am zooming the body using [CSS3's zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/) property and calculating windows height and width. Its just the body that zooms in and zooms out while window's dimensions remains the same.

Now when I test this script in Firefox I get uniform window dimensions every time the page is zoomed in or out (ideal case). However in IE thats not the case. It oscillates back and forth from (1004 X 358) to (6807 X 2500), with absolutely no window resize. I got the same readings when I used `clientWidth` & `clientHeight`.

I have also attached console log screenshot of IE 9. I want to know whether if there's any way I could get actual window dimensions while using `zoom` property. Any suggestions are welcome.

I am using the following doctype

> < !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >

Interestingly I get correct dimensions when I use **< !DOCTYPE HTML>**, but then the zoom doesn't work. Is there any way I could get the right dimensions and also the working zoom?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`zoom` isn't a CSS3 property, but a pure MS invention, which is quite old and also means that they can do what ever they want.

When you use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to trigger Standardsmode, then in newer IEs you need to use `-ms-zoom` instead of `zoom`.

Assuming your tests are correct, I'd suggest instead of trying to work around IE's buggy behavior is to look at the bigger picture, but for that I'd need to knpw: Why are do you need to know how large the window is? Why are you using `zoom`? What about the real CSS3 property `transform`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am actually displaying large images on my website.. what I want is when user resizes browser window, I could zoom the images based on window height and width. I am using zoom for that.. You think I can use transform for the same?

Comment: No need to use JavaScript for that. Just use `width: 100%` on the image, possibly adding reasonable px values for `min-with` and `max-width`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JLZzq/

Comment: thanks a lot, I'd surely give it a try. But still any idea why was I getting those weird window dimensions?

Comment: MS most likely implemented `zoom` by internally adjusting the canvas size, but the adjustments to return the original values vie JavaScript are buggy.